# Opensource alternative to mobiscroll

Tags: datetime, open-source, datepicker, scroll, responsive-design

I am following a tutorial found here:

http://stevenbooks.com/2012/09/28/jquery-datetime-mobile-picker/

however when it comes to adding the iPhone like scroll wheels for selecting date/time the suggested "mobiscroll" has a hefty license fee.

http://mobiscroll.com/

I was hoping someone new of an opensource alternative that would offer similar functionality.

it is primarily for aesthetics as this date/time picker is intended to be accessed primarily across mobile devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core of mobiscroll is open source, as per their [FAQ page](http://mobiscroll.com/faq). Looking on the code their, it looks pretty complete.

> The mobiscroll core is open source, and you can build your own custom
>   scrollers with it. The easiest way to get started with mobiscroll
>   development is through our GitHub page.

Comment: Are you sure about the open source license? I couldn't find it in there [FAQ page](http://help.mobiscroll.com/en/articles/708887-faq).
Only [Mobiscroll Lite](https://mobiscroll.com/pricing#lite) is free which is not having datepicker as part of it.